# What is the meaning and appropriate usage of "fazer com que"?

Tags: verbos, tradução-inglês

Here are some examples:**

> Bancos têm de **fazer com que** o cliente distinga produtos com e sem risco
>
> **Faremos com que** o caminho da violência para a política seja mais difícil de percorrer.
>
> Chegou a hora de virar a página e de **fazer com que** a projecto europeu encarrilhe de novo.

It seems that the word means **to make or to cause something to happen** ("make the client distinguish", "make the path harder" and "make the project restart", respectively). Is that roughly correct and a good guide to when this verb should be used?

I'm also curious if this way of speaking has some ties to formality/informality or regional dialects. Some [corners of the internet](https://lusografias.wordpress.com/2007/03/11/fazer-com-que-ou-fazer-que/) have reported that *fazer com que* is ungrammatical; if that's true, does it influence where it is appropriate to use it?

---

** The first quote is a [May 2015 headline](http://economico.sapo.pt/noticias/carlos-costa-bancos-tem-de-fazer-com-que-o-cliente-distinga-produtos-com-e-sem-risco_217501.html), and the other two were on [bab.la's text search](http://en.bab.la/dictionary/portuguese-english/fazer-com-que) (a line from a TED talk, and from European Parliamentary proceedings).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not a phrasal verb, but it means exactly what you said, *to make*. The "com" may be dropped, and no meaning is lost – but emphasis and euphony are.

Note that this is only used with verbs in the subjunctive:

fazer com que eu vá
*fazer com que eu vou

---

<sub>* means the sentence is agrammatical</sub>